# magento 1.6 multiple website under IIS

Tags: php, iis, magento

I got windows server 2008 r2 standard virtual server with godaddy.

I have magento community 1.6.1.0 deployed under IIS 7.5 and it is working fine.

I tried to follow this link to use one backend to manage multiple website

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work

I have created a foolder in the same level as the base magento install folder 
copy index.php and .htaccess file here, modify index.php to Mage::run(’mysite1’, ‘website’); 
create a new website in IIS and pointed to this folder 
configure the web tab for the scoop of this new website to configure the base url and secure base url

problem is that when i visit the new domain, it always redirect to the base website the default magento store.

i did a bit search, some post said “redirect to base url option”, but it is nowhere to be found. 
i also tried to set “Auto-redirect to Base URL” to no, but it is not helping.

can anyone help me out of this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a different index.php

if your main site is www.mainsite.com and is "mainsite" in Magento AND your new domain is www.anothersite.com and is "anothersite" then put this code in your index.php :

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
  case 'www.mainsite.com' :
    Mage::run('mainsite', 'website');
    break;

  case 'www.anothersite.com' :
    Mage::run('anothersite', 'website');
    break;

  default:
    Mage::run();
}
```

Personally I prefer to use Mage::run('anothersite', 'store');

Now - VERY IMPORTANT - you need to go into Magento config where you put the FRONT and BACKEND URLS in and switch to the new website level. You can then override the default and put in the new domain.

Hope this helps - if you need further expansion on the solution please let me know

Barny

Comment: Hi Barny, thanks for your help. I managed to get it working.
I created another site under IIS and point to the same folder as the default install folder.
I put what you suggested into the index.php file
I go admin --> configure --> web base url and secure base url
then it is working great.

just one other thing, i remember someone said put something like this into .hcaccess file

Comment: SetEnvIf Host .*ugg\.ultimateluxuryfashion\.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE='base'
SetEnvIf Host .*ugg\.ultimateluxuryfashion\.com.*
MAGE_RUN_TYPE='website'

SetEnvIf Host .*bags\.ultimateluxuryfashion\.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE='bags1'
SetEnvIf Host .*bags\.ultimateluxuryfashion\.com.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE='website'

Comment: but it does not work out, do you have any idea about this solution? why it is not working?

Comment: IIS does not interpret .htaccess files, you have to use it's alternative which are web.config files: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config

Answer (score 0):

It is meant to be done via the .htaccess file. You should add the following code at the bottom:

```
# domain1.com
SetEnvIf Host domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1
SetEnvIf Host domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

# domain2.com
SetEnvIf Host domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2
SetEnvIf Host domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

The MAGE_RUN_CODE must correspond to the website code you have entered in the Magento backoffice when creating that website.

Comment: somehow it does not work, i leave the index.php as default and add the above code to .htaccess, it always redirect to base website.

Comment: somehow it does not work, i leave the index.php as default and add the above code to .htaccess, it always redirect to base website.
but if i modify the index.php, it works.
i also want to use .htaccess approach, can you help me out of this?
i'm a .net developer, does not know much about php.
is it working under IIS? do i need to do something for the settings in .htaccess work? or it just works in IIS?

Comment: As far as I know Magento does not officially support running in a Windows Environment. Are you sure IIS is reading/using the .htaccess file?

Comment: IIS does not use .htaccess file, i have to use index.php file to achieve this